# Menu scroll-bar using jquery or javascript for mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-mobile

I want to create a menu scrollbar for mobile application which should scroll by dragging finger on it. It could be by using javascript or jquery. I want to use it in mobile web application creating in JSP.

Please help.

Comment: This should be simple menu bar without any submenus

Comment: That's still not very clear. Can you show us a sketch? How should it scroll? What range of devices are you trying to accomodate?

Comment: It should have 5-6 elements in div tag like home, users, tags, questions etc but it should only show 2-3 at the moment and rest should show when I scroll it left or right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use iScroll to make scrollable areas for mobile devices. It's pretty light-weight and got quite a few options: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

You can create horizontal/vertical/2D scrollable areas, you can snap to elements, easily refresh the scrollable area if the content changes, and iScroll adds scrollbars which are customizable.

Comment: Hi Jasper, Thanks for your answer could you please help me where do I need to change if I want to make it horizontally

Comment: I have used iscroll as well, though we ultimately decided that scrolling parts of a page across all the devices we needed to support (ios, android, BlackBerry, Nokia, etc) proved to just be too much work and not necessarily great UX for our users. @user965884 note that horizontal scrolling on a mobile phone's web browser isn't necessarily the most intuitive UX.

Comment: Hi DA, Thanks for your comments, I just need a horizontal menu bar which is same as in Fox news mobile application.

Comment: Look under the "Passing parameters to the iScroll" heading on the iScroll 4 website. If you set `hscroll` to `true` and `vScroll` to `false` you will get a horizontal scroller. Note that the element you are scrolling needs to be wider than its container (the element you call iScroll on) to be scrollable. @DA that is a good point, if you want to introduce your users to a horizontal scroller, make sure there is a visual queue for your users that they can scroll the region.